# Cannot extract zip file linked using Angular on Mac or Windows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<a class="link-text =" ng-href="static/sample-impact-results-to-upload.zip" download>Download Sample File</a>
```

I am not able to unzip downloaded zip file in mac when I am trying to open it. It is getting converted into another file with **.zip.gpgz** extension. In windows, it says invalid zip. I am using angularjs 1.6.
When I remove the download attribute it works in local machine but it does not work in the cloud.

Comment: If it says invalid zip it will be invalid, how are you creating the zip file?

Comment: this is a static file which has been stored. I am trying to give a relative path in href.

Comment: one more information it works on the local machine, but when I am creating a docker image and deploy on the cloud it does not work.

Comment: Can you try `ng-href="./static/sample-impact-results-to-upload.zip"`

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: it does not work because I think this is not a path problem otherwise download throws 404.

Comment: This looks like a routing problem, Is there anyway you can use a absolute path like `ng-href="http://your-site.com/static/sample-impact-results-to-upload.zip"`

Comment: One more information - When I remove the download attribute it works in my local machine but does not work on cloud.